# WPF does not seem to find a custom attached property

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I am trying to bind a property (Button.Background) to a property on my custom attached property.

In a C# file I have

```
public static class Square
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
        (
            name           : "Player",
            propertyType   : typeof(Player),
            ownerType      : typeof(UIElement),
            defaultMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    public static Player GetPlayer(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Player)element.GetValue(PlayerProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPlayer(UIElement element, Player player)
    {
        element.SetValue(PlayerProperty, player);
    }

    // Other attached properties
}
```

A snippet of my XAML is

```
<Grid Name="board" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{Binding Path=(l:Square.Player).Brush, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

This is the error I get:

> Cannot convert string '(l:Square.Player).Brush' in attribute 'Path' to object of type 'System.Windows.PropertyPath'.
>
> Property path is not valid. 'Square' does not have a public property named 'Player'.
>
> Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'Gobang.Gui;component/mainwindow.xaml' Line 148 Position 59.

But since `Player` is an attached property which is on `Square`, the above code should work, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your attached property should designate Square as the owner rather than UIElement.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Player", typeof(Player),
        typeof(Square), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the intellisense tooltip, sigh. The binding doesn't quite work (the background doesn't change), but that should just be some silly thing I'll look at tomorrow. Thanks a lot, I had wasted so much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.
Note: its a read-only property, the Helper class HAS TO inherit from DependencyObject

```
public class Helper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsExpandedKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
        "IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(Helper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty = IsExpandedKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static bool GetIsExpanded(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(IsExpandedKey.DependencyProperty);
    }

    internal static void SetIsExpanded(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(IsExpandedKey, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't set up a binding in the way that you're doing it - you'll need an instance of either `Square` or `Player` to bind to that.

Comment: I'm not trying to bind to an instance of Square, Square is where my attached property declaration is.